# Proof of directional derivative chain rule

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, derivatives, chain-rule

I'm trying to prove that: $\frac{\partial g(f(\vec{a}))}{\partial\vec{v}} = g'(f(\vec{a}))\cdot\frac{\partial f(\vec{a})}{\partial \vec{v}}$

I have tried the following: $\frac{\partial g(f(\vec{a}))}{\partial\vec{v}} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{g(f(\vec{a}+h\vec{v}))-g(f(\vec{a}))}{h}$

But I don't know if this step is correct or how to continue. Any tips are welcome!

Comment: Hint: The directional derivative is just $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(\vec a_0+t\vec v)$. Now use the multivariable chain rule to calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(g\circ f\circ h(t))$, where $h(t)=\vec a_0+t\vec v$.

Comment: Thank you for your help!